# How to find a blocking operation or other operation that takes a long time?

Tags: python, performance, pycharm

I am using Python 2.7 with Pycharm.

I have a very large project, and somewhere in the stack there is a function that takes an abnormal amount of time to complete.

I tried to time my functions manually (adding `start = time.time()` and `end = time.time()` and displaying `end-start`) but there are a lot of functions, a lot of iterations and recursive calls. Logging times didn't help. I also tried to use the debugger, but debugging by clicking through the code skews the actual computation time.

Can anyone suggest a better way of determining which function in my project takes a long time?

**ANSWER**

PyCharm has an integrated profiler, so I used that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can you profile a python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: What you are trying to do is called profiling, you need a profiler for Python

Comment: Thanks! I'll try cProfiler and let you know how it went!

Comment: If it's a particular function invocation that's being abnormal, just run the program and kill it part-way through. The traceback should include the problematic function with reasonably high likelihood. Repeat this a few times to make sure you've got the right thing.